# preg_match user validation

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to make a **preg_match** rule for user validation

to only allow a-z - A-Z - 0-9 
and the characters _-=?!@:., 
without spaces

I already tried a lot of combinations but no one seems to work

This is what im trying to get:

```
    if(preg_match('idk what to use here', 'Myusername@123?')) {
        return true;
    }

    if(preg_match('idk what to use here', '$Hello')) {
        return false;
    }

    if(preg_match('idk what to use here', 'Hello 123')) {
        return false;
    }
```

Anyone knows the regex for this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class, but make sure to either escape the hyphen or put it as the last character, otherwise it signifies a range. Use `^` and `$` to require that all input characters match the pattern:

```
$regex = "/^[A-Za-z0-9_=?!@:.,-]*$/";

var_dump(preg_match($regex, 'Myusername@123?'));
var_dump(preg_match($regex, '$Hello'));
var_dump(preg_match($regex, 'Hello 123'));
```